# How do I open a new file from Terminal to a tab instead of a new window on MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I moved `mvim` to `/usr/local/bin`, so from Terminal if I type `mvim file.html`, then MacVim will open in a new window and open the file `file.html`.

But if I open another file from Terminal, then it will open *another* MacVim window.

Is it possible open the new file as a new tab on MacVim?

I currently have the MacVim setting as

```
Open files from application: in the current window
    with a tab for each file
```

But that only open new files in a new tab only if I open the file from MacVim (not running `mvim` from the Terminal).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This hack](http://webexpose.org/2008/10/13/open-macvim-tabs-from-command-line/comment-page-1/#comment-95424) should work, but it may be frustrating to maintain every time that MacVim is updated. It requires you to edit the mvim script. This seems to be a longstanding and known issue.

```
mvim `which mvim`

## Add the following line to the top of the file, below the commented section:

tabs=true

## Replace the `if` structure at the bottom of the file with the following:

# Last step:  fire up vim.
if [ "$gui" ]; then
  if $tabs && [[ `$binary --serverlist` = "VIM" ]]; then
    exec "$binary" -g $opts --remote-tab-silent ${1:+"$@"}
  else
    exec "$binary" -g $opts ${1:+"$@"}
  fi
else
  exec "$binary" $opts ${1:+"$@"}
fi
```

Comment: Perfect. It did exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!